# FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext(); returning null in wcm.io

Tags: unit-testing

We are getting NULL for below line when we are using wcm.io framework for writing junit for aem codebase.

```
BundleContext bctx = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any particular mocking framework and how are your mocks setup?

Comment: We are using wcm.io framework and AemContext builder class for populating objects. Please find below peace of code may be it will help full public static AemContext newAemContext() { 
    return new AemContextBuilder().resourceResolverType(ResourceResolverType.JCR_MOCK)
        .plugin(WCMIO_SLING, WCMIO_CONFIG, WCMIO_HANDLER)
        .afterSetUp(SETUP_CALLBACK)
        .build();
    }

Comment: In test Class we are getting AemContext object by this line  @Rule
 public final AemContext context = ServletAEMContext.newAemContext();